# Adding tinyMCE to multiple dynamically created textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of dynamically created textareas with content in them. Below is how I retrieve the data and create the textareas dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#btn').click(function(){
    var fullurl = $('#hiddenurl').val();
    var str = $('#email').val();
    $.post(fullurl, {
        sendValue : str
    }, function(data) {
        var table_output = '<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead>';
    $.each(data, function(i, d) {
        table_output += '<tr><td>'+d.Name+'</td><td>'+d.Email+'</td></tr>';
        output += '<tr><td colspan="2"><textarea name="description" id="desc_'+d.ID+'" class="desc">'+d.Description+'</textarea></td></tr>';            

        tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "exact",
            elements : 'desc_'+d.ID,
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "mylistbox,mysplitbutton,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom"
        });

    });
 table_output += '</table>';
 $('#task_data_div').append(table_output);
```

I tried implementing tinyMCE as show above however it does not seem to work. Can anyone help me out here and maybe point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had to factor out your Ajax call for simplicity, but my `#btn` click handler will drop in to your success handler transparently.

Demonstration (jsFiddle)
http://jsfiddle.net/C59EW/

HTML

```
<button id="btn">button</button>
<div id="show_data"></div>
```

Javascript (+jQuery, +tinyMCE)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var data = [{ID:"1",Description:"text 1"}, {ID:"2",Description:"text 2"}];

    $('#btn').click( function() {
        $.each( data, function(i, d) {
            $('#show_data').append('<textarea name="description" id="desc_'+d.ID+'" class="desc">'+d.Description+'</textarea>');
            tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "exact",
                elements : 'desc_'+d.ID,
                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "mylistbox,mysplitbutton,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink",
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom"
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi @T.W.R. Cole can you please take a look at that new code I updated at the top? I have to deal with a table sadly, and I tried adding you implementation to my code and sadly it breaks my table :S can you suggest me something? Thank you very much!

Comment: You changed an important piece of logic: the append call has to precede the call to tinyMCE.init(). It's rather crucial.

Comment: Given my situation, how would I achieve that since I have to append the </table> tag at the end.

Comment: You might have to have two $.each(...) loops then. One to create all your tables and plain text areas, and then another to "enhance" all the textareas into tinyMCE components